# Is it possible to save a list of a vectors in a matrix?

Tags: r

Suppose I a have a list of vectors, say `x <-rnorm(10)`, `y <- rnorm(10)` 
and `z <- list(x,y)`.Then, I could save each of them in a matrix, i.e., `Mat <- matrix(x, 10, 10)`.

I would like to have a `2` by `2` lower triangular matrix where the values of this matrix are `x` and `y`.

Mat  =

```
0        0 

z[[1]]  z[[2]]
```

Then, I can extract the values of `x` or `y` from this matrix. That is I can extract all the `10` values of each vector. For example,

`Mat[2,1]` will print me all the `10` values of `x`.

Is that possible?

I have one possible idea, however, do not really know how to implement it in `R` code. My idea is to give `x` and `y` a name as a number. Then, create a matrix using these numbers. However, calling this number will return the values of `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
x <- seq(10, 19, 1)
y <- seq(20, 29, 1) 
z <- list(x,y)

Mat <- matrix(unlist(z), ncol=2)

Mat[,1]
# [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

Mat[,2]
# [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
```

Comment: I do not know how to thank you. Thanks so much. It is really a clever answer.